# How to make transparent JLayeredPane() and JPanel()? It always shows background of super window

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, ubuntu, awt

How can i completely make this **grey panel as transparent**, so that i can see only the **button "Test"** but not the grey box (JPanel or JLayeredPane)

Screen shot: [image]

```
public class win extends JWindow 
{
    ...

    public win() 
    {
        super(new JFrame());
        layers = new JLayeredPane();
        button = new JButton("close");

        this.setLayout (new BorderLayout ());
        ..

        button.setBackground(Color.RED);
        button.setSize(200,200);
        button.setLocation(0,20);
        this.add("North", button);

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setOpaque(false);
        p.setSize(300, 200);
        p.setLocation(0, 0);
        p.add(new JButton("Test"));

        layers.add(p, new Integer(1));
        layers.setSize(400,300);
        layers.setLocation(400,50);
        layers.setOpaque(false);
        this.add("North", layers);

        canvas.setSize(screenSize.width,screenSize.height);
        this.add("North",canvas);
        //com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity(this, 0.5f); // gives error in my Java version

    }
}
```

**Follow up:** installed as recommended, but no luck yet.

```
ERROR not solved: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The TRANSLUCENT translucency kind is not supported.

Installed:
  compiz-gnome.i686 0:0.9.4-2.fc15                                                      

Dependency Installed:
  compiz-gtk.i686 0:0.9.4-2.fc15           compiz-plugins-main.i686 0:0.9.4-1.fc15     
  libcompizconfig.i686 0:0.9.4-1.fc15      protobuf.i686 0:2.3.0-7.fc15                

Complete!
You have mail in /var/spool/mail/root
[root@example ~]# xdpyinfo | grep -i render
    RENDER
You have mail in /var/spool/mail/root
[root@example ~]# xdpyinfo | grep -i comp
    Composite
    XVideo-MotionCompensation
[root@example ~]#
```

Comment: Is that your desktop in the background or does the JFrame have a background image?

Comment: @Charles Goodwin: JFrame has > Canvas and that having the background image.

Comment: Are you running this in Eclipse or another I.D.E.? Using AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity is restricted, I believe, so you have to modify the settings for it to work. Here's a link to fixing that in Eclipse: http://lkamal.blogspot.com/2008/09/eclipse-access-restriction-on-library.html

Comment: @Zéychin: I am using NetBeans IDE nightly builds.

Comment: Try finding a similar dialog in NetBeans to the one describe in the post I linked. I'm not familiar enough with NetBeans to help with that.

Beyond that, I don't think it would hurt for you to try it out in Eclipse.

Comment: I think that you maybe made a huge newbee mistake, look here `public class win extends JWindow` aaaaaaand contains `super#JFrame`, which of `Top-Level Containers` is finally marked with `this#anyMethods`, which one `JWindow` or `JFrame` :-)

Comment: @mKorbel: Right, JWindow does not require super. Other once i use for code highlight such as this.xxxxxxx but still the problem exist. Nothing solved yet so far.

Comment: just my curiosity: is required usage of OpenJDK in your case???, then why ???

Comment: @mKorbel: OpenJDK is already playing and running correctly this one: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/TranslucentShapes.jnlp

Comment: my question has deepest base, cos if I reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK, then there are at first sight some differencies between stable (Oracle JDK) and open-source OpenJDK, maybe OpenJDK is for minor OS Platform, my bad and true is that I never ever tried and compile something on minor platform as Solaris(dbadmin), just runs Apps compiled on Win platform,

Comment: @mKorbel: You are right. But when any JNLP file gets executed in my system is it using Sun Java or Open JDK? Its using atleast something!! and i mean that is working. But not my compiled code from NetBeans IDE.

Comment: that the problem, are you remember instalations steps, when Netbeans identified JDK's for/as base for compilator ..., JVM is for running compiled classes or jars, JDK is for compile from form *.java to runnable bytecode for JVM :-), but be sure that NetBeans has own compilator, that in some cases doesn't correspondent with compile from command line, but output must be same (I hoping in that)

Comment: when you do `update-alternatives --config java` and `update-alternatives --config javaws` you should see which java and java web start versions you are currently using (if you run these commands with `sudo` you can also change where the `java` and `javaws` commands point to). For example, when I run `javaws http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/TranslucentShapes.jnlp` on the command line with OpenJDK selected for javaws I get an exception that it does not find the class `com/sun/awt/AWTUtilities`.

Comment: And when you see the Oracle splash screen when starting the demo with web start, you're running the Sun/Oracle JDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this article](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html) or [this article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/). Note that not all environments support all the features (translucency, per pixel transparencyt etc.) described in the article.

**EDIT**: On my system (Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS, Sun java 1.6.0_26) the following code:

```
  System.out.println("TRANSLUCENT supported:          " + AWTUtilities.isTranslucencySupported(AWTUtilities.Translucency.TRANSLUCENT));
  System.out.println("PERPIXEL_TRANSPARENT supported: " + AWTUtilities.isTranslucencySupported(AWTUtilities.Translucency.PERPIXEL_TRANSPARENT));
  System.out.println("PERPIXEL_TRANSLUCENT supported: " + AWTUtilities.isTranslucencySupported(AWTUtilities.Translucency.PERPIXEL_TRANSLUCENT));
```

gives:

```
TRANSLUCENT supported:          false
PERPIXEL_TRANSPARENT supported: true
PERPIXEL_TRANSLUCENT supported: true
```

**EDIT2:** Inspired by [this discussion](http://www.java.net/node/678905), I just installed and configured `compiz` and now the 'constant opacity level' slider of the web start application at the second article linked above suddenly can be moved to values smaller than 100% and the demo frame actually is translucent. Also the code snipped shown above now prints `true` for all three kinds of translucency/transparency. And `AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity(..)` does not throw any more but produces a transparent window.

Comment: This solution works perfectly for (most) environments. I've used this many times before. I went and gave a game I made that "WinAMP" kind of treatment. What's really useful is if you just make the whole window transparent and then overlay a simple graphic with some transparency over it to shape your window.

Comment: @Zéychin: Yes the links from @Andre Holzner showing its working. But never worked for me yet under Ubuntu/Fedora/Linux.

Comment: See my comment on original post. It may be because of restricted libraries.

Comment: @Andre Holzner: Yes this is the error it shows and fail to move forward. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The TRANSLUCENT translucency kind is not supported.

Comment: incidentally, I just tried to create translucent windows yesterday but gave up when I saw that my environment does not support it :-)

Comment: @Andre Holzner: Strange i went to the link above and i launched this file: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/TranslucentShapes.jnlp  and i test that demo. Which is working. But why not our code is working?

Comment: @Andre Holzner: I installed compiz too. But mine is not yet solved. I still get error in my NetBeans IDE.

Comment: second link is broken